# Unity - Vuforia - Raycast Hits work fine on Unity Editor but bugs on Android Device build

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, raycasting

for my bachelor thesis im augmenting a physical paper map. Therefor as written in the title im using unity in combination with vuforia for imagetarget detection and further functions.

So far so good.

Now the problem:

Im using cube elements that are augmented beside the map as interaction elements to filter the projected content. Those cubes have box colliders on em. I attached the following "buttonController" script to my AR camera which should handle the Raycast hits on those cubes and trigger further functions.

```
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.Events;

using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ButtonController : MonoBehaviour
{
public AudioClip[] audioClips;
public AudioSource myAudioSource;

private string btnName;
private GameObject[] stations;

private void Start()
{
    myAudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

private void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {

        //Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        Vector3 tapPositionFar = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.farClipPlane);
        Vector3 tapPositionNear = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane);

        Vector3 tapPosF = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(tapPositionFar);
        Vector3 tapPosN = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(tapPositionNear);

        int layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Button", "Pin");
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(tapPosN, tapPosF - tapPosN, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        {

            btnName = hit.transform.name;
            Debug.Log("NAME OF HIT TARGET: " + hit.transform.name);

            myAudioSource.clip = audioClips[0];
            myAudioSource.Play();

            switch (btnName)
            {
                case "buttonRoute1":
                    Debug.Log("In: CASE 1");

                    playAnimation(btnName);
                    stations = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Route1");

                    Debug.Log(stations);

                    LineRenderer lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

                    foreach (GameObject station in stations)
                    {
                        MeshRenderer mRenderer = station.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
                        if (mRenderer.enabled == true)
                        {
                            mRenderer.enabled = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mRenderer.enabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                    return;

                case "buttonRoute2":
                    Debug.Log("In: CASE 2");
                    playAnimation(btnName);
                    return;

                case "buttonRoute3":
                    Debug.Log("In: CASE 3");
                    playAnimation(btnName);
                    return;

                case "buttonRoute4":
                    Debug.Log("In: CASE 4");
                    playAnimation(btnName);
                    return;

                case "buttonRoute5":
                    Debug.Log("In: CASE 5");
                    playAnimation(btnName);
                    return;

                case "buttonRoute6":
                    Debug.Log("In: CASE 6");
                    playAnimation(btnName);
                    return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 1000, Color.white);
            Debug.Log("NOTHING HAPPENED WITH MOUSE");
        }
    }
}

void playAnimation(string btnName)
{
    GameObject currentGameObject = GameObject.Find(btnName);
    Animation anim = currentGameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
    anim.Play();
}
```

}

This cubes are set to special XZ coordinates in the unity scene and do **not** get moved programmatically during runtime in another script.

I also augment pins which are placed on the 0/0/0 of an imagetarget and get repositioned during runtime to new XZ coordinates calculated by their LatLong coordinates. Their Raycast hits are detected aswell by the above script.

When i run my application in the editor everything works perfectly fine. Each of the elements, the cubes and the pins, get hit by the raycast exactly like they should.

So far so good.

When i build the android version and install it to my xiaomi android phone the raycasts dont hit like they should. I dont get any hit at all when i touch the cubes on their original position beside the map. **BUT** i get hits in the blue marked area seen in the picture below.

[My unity scene showing the cube buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUV9S.jpg)

It looks like the boxcolliders of the cubes on the side get all move onto the 0/0/0 position of my imagetarget during runtime although the models keep their original position.

The pins dont get any hits at all although they have active mesh colliders on them and get hit in the editor too.

Im extremely desperate now since ive already tried like each and every advice i found in thousands of threats.

I tried setting up a new AR camera element, move the script to another object, change hierarchy, change colliders, reset colliders, different raycast scripts from mouseclick to touch, use a different device, ... and so on.

I would appreciate it SO MUCH if anyone of you might have a hint what the problem could be.

If more information would be needed just let me know!

Thanks so far.
Greetings

EDIT:

@Philipp Lenssen and others

Like i already said i think the colliders move during the runtime. I debugged the colliders of buttonRoute 1 and buttonRoute 2 while hitting the blue marked zone from screenshot 1.

I get hits and the colliders position is completely different.

[marked green and yellow Cubes are cubes to visualize the boxcolliders of Route 1 and Route 2 Button cube beside the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNIDu.jpg)

They are not even at the same wrong position. One is above the 0 of Y axis and one underneath. Their X and Z coordinates are completely wierd. They should keep the position of the Green Route 2 and Yellow Route 1 button 3d elements shown beside the map!

I have NO idea why this happens....

EDIT:

Ive rebuild the entire project to a new clean one. I also updated my Android SDK to the latest version. **Now the app works BUGFREE!**

Comment: Hi! Have you managed to get a debug connection going to the Android build via Android Debug Bridge (adb), so you can see if there's any errors? Sometimes errors symptomatically cause other parts of the app to fail, i.e. there may already be something bugging out with your object in question before the whole raycasts get a chance to hit.

Comment: Hey Phillip. Yes, ive already debugged e.g. the raycasts via the Windows Cmd. Nothing special in there sadly... It didnt show any Errors/critical Errors at all. What i havent debugged so far is something like the collider position on runtime If this is possible. I'll have it a try later and give Feedback on that.      But in General: is it even possible that colliders leave their Position apart from the original 3d model?!

Comment: @PhilippLenssen see EDIT above

Comment: Colliders sometimes flunk out, then you are left with a colliderless object which can't be lasered anymore, yes. In my case, it's in a software allowing people to create their own meshes, and sometimes the mesh combine will bug out on some shapes. (With some of my issues, there weren't even catch-try-loggable, for some reasons, and I rarely encountered that in Unity.) I'm not sure if it's related to your case, though, may well be something entirely different.

Comment: But so you have any conclusion in that issue? I have no Idea what to do to prevent them from bugging. Did you try to reposition them in the start of the update function as a workaround? So you think this would work out?

Comment: I encountered at least 3 different mesh issues, not all of them try-catchable (all of them showed in the Editor too though, so may not be your issue). 1, non-kinematic rigidbodies on convex mesh colliders, which Unity can't cope with. 2, too-flat user-made meshes after a meshCombine, with which inflateMesh didn't help either. 3, a too-high indicies count on a merge, which is preventable when counting them though, and you can also change to a higher count in recent versions of Unity.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer mate ... still dont have any answer for my problem. =(. Regarding your Ideas: i dont use any rigidbody or convex collider in my application since the only hit on them is or should be by touching the device display once. I i do use Mesh Colliders on my selfmade 3d Pin models but not on the cubes. there i only use box colliders. Which means this is most likely no answer aswell =(. What do you mean bout the indicies count on merge? And what is this count that you are talking about?

Comment: When using 16 bit index buffers for mesh vertices, you can't exceed 65535 vertices. In my case, when that count is about to exceed, I switch to 32 bit, supporting 4 billion vertices. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-indexFormat.html This may not be your issue as it would show in Editor as well, though there is mention of Android in above page; "GPU support for 32 bit indices is not guaranteed on all platforms; for example Android devices with Mali-400 GPU do not support them. When using 32 bit indices on such a platform, a warning message will be logged and mesh will not render."

Comment: (Can't add long comments on StackOverflow, but just wanted to add, as your issue seems to be a collision mesh location displacement, above is unlikely to be the issue. Just explaining it as you asked.)

Comment: PS: Is there a kind of Vuforia forum you can ask in? Maybe it's something intricate to AR which they heard of?

Comment: I see. Doesnt sound like my issue as you have already mentioned. Thanks anyway. There are Vuforia Forums, yes. But none of em is especially for Collider problems. Ive already written a post there but no answer so far… the feedback there is sadly pretty lame

Comment: Just a random thought. What happens if you create your boxes without a collider at start. Then, say, 4 seconds after `Start()`, you add them (`gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>()`). Will they still seemingly be at Vector3.zero?

Comment: (Another random thought: Are you able to test the build on another AR-compatible Android phone, just to rule pinpoint if this has anything to do with Xiaomi in particular.)

Comment: Ive already tried on a samsung aswell. Same problem =/

Comment: Regarding your though about adding the colliders on runtime. I havent tried this so far and i definitly will try this  out. The problem is i have 5 cubes that need box colliders and probably about 40 to 50 meshcolliders for the pins.

Comment: Adding colliders on Runtime makes no difference aswell...

Comment: Sometimes as last resort it can help to create a minimalist, isolated new project to reproduce just this issue. In other words, to create a new Unity project, add 1 cube + AR camera + ray, then build for device and check if the issue persists. If that fixes it, you'd then work your way back towards the full feature set, and see where it breaks first. If that doesn't fix it, then you at least have a project you can easily share with people who may want to help.

Comment: ye true story... i guess thats all i can do for now..

Comment: @PhilipLenssen Thanks alot for each of try to help me!! At the end ive rebuild the entire project into a clean new project. Im am finally at where i was before BUT now all is working exactly as i should on my Android device. The bug is gone!!! No idea how this fixed it. What i also did is updating my android SDK since i found out i am using not the latest one. Maybe that was the reason.

Comment: Oh wow! Congrats.